# Is there a sequence $\mathbb{N}^*\to\mathbb{N}^*$, not depending on the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, whose convergence is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

I think this is rather a naive question, so please forgive me for asking this.

In the Wikipedia page [List of statements independent of ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC), it is stated that "One can write down a concrete polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_9]$ such that it can neither be proven nor disproven in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $p$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Z}^9$ (assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent)." Since this is a polynomial written out concretely, the polynomial does not depend on the concrete model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$; what's astonishing is that the question whether the polynomial has a zero does, however.

So I was curious about if there is a similar phenomenon for the integer sequences. Is there a sequence in $\mathbb{N}^*$, not depending on the concrete model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, such that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ neither proves nor disproves its convergence? A sequence like $a_{2n}=0$, $a_{2n-1}=\begin{cases} 1, \text{if }\mathsf{CH}\text{ holds}\\ 0, \text{if not}\end{cases}$ depends on the model, so it is not what I am looking for. Thank you for any help in advance, and please don't hesitate to correct me for any mistakes. In addition, if such a sequence exists, a few terms provided whenever possible would be appreciated.

Comment: "the polynomial does not depend on the concrete model of ZFC" - I don't really get what you mean by this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Z.A.K. Please forgive me I am wrong by holding this belief. A polynomial (or rather some numbers) explicitly written out, like $5$ for example, should has the same meaning in any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, no?

Comment: The notion of "same meaning in all models" is more subtle than one would think, and is certainly not a standard definition one would find in a standard logic textbook; I'm trying to gauge what sort of object you'd accept as having the same meaning in all models.

Comment: For example, does  "the empty set" have the same meaning in all models of ZFC? After all, given a model $M$ of ZFC, I can construct another model $M'$ so that the unique $S \in M$ so that $\forall x \in M. x \not\in_M S$ and the unique $S'$ in $M'$ so that $\forall x \in M'. x \not\in_{M'} S'$ satisfy $S \neq S'$. Does that mean "the empty set" does not have the same meaning in the two models?

Comment: One could play around with things like transitive models to get a better grip on what's "the same meaning", but I have the feeling that it'll be quite difficult to obtain one that a.) successfully distinguishes between objects like your $a_n$ and objects like the polynomial which comes from Gödel's incompleteness theorem and b.) is not hopelessly dependent on metatheoretic considerations.

Comment: But before you think about the definition, let me ask something more specific, would you say that the following *has the same meaning* in all models of ZFC? Enumerate all ZFC proofs that can be written down using $n$ letters (there are finitely many). If you see a proof of $0=1$ among them, set $a_n = n$, otherwise set $a_n = 0$." This sequence $a$ diverges to infinity precisely if there is some proof of $0=1$ in ZFC, i.e. if ZFC is inconsistent. But by Gödel 2, if ZFC is consistent, then ZFC can't prove its own consistency, and so it can't prove $a$ convergent. If so, that's an answer.

Comment: Better yet, consider the same polynomial $p$ as above: define $a_n = n$ if this $p$ has a zero in a radius $n$ disk around the origin of $\mathbb{Z}^9$, and $a_n = 0$ otherwise. Whatever reasonable definition of "the same meaning" one could cook up, as long as $p$ has the same meaning in every model, so would the sequence $a$. And clearly ZFC proves $a$ convergent precisely if $p$ has a zero (NB the summary of Matiyasevich's theorem in the List of... article is a bit fast-and-loose, refer to [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) for details)

Comment: @Z.A.K. It occurs to me that the set $\omega$ depends on the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so a sequence cannot be independent of it since the domain is... What I thought was, suppose that we see an explicitly defined natural number, say $5=s_M(s_M(s_M(s_M(s_M(\emptyset_M)))))$ in a model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, I would then like to think that it has the same meaning as $s_{M'}(s_{M'}(s_{M'}(s_{M'}(s_{M'}(\emptyset_{M'})))))$ in another model $M'$.

Comment: @Z.A.K. I like these example, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Z.A.K. Just of cuiosity: when the Wikipedia says "a concrete polynomial", what does that mean? Can we concretely write down all natural numbers less than, say, $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$, to see if the polynomial has a zero in the disk of radius $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all the tuples in $\mathbb{Z}^9$ and define $a_n:=n$ if there is $i<n$ such that the $i$-th tuple is a zero for the fixed polynomial $p$ you described, and $a_n:=0$ otherwise. Then this sequence converges iff $p$ does not have a zero.

Comment: But how do we know that the polynomial has infinitely many zeros if it has one? And also, this sequence depends on the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (being entirely $0$ in a model where $p$ has no zero, and not otherwise), no?

Comment: If you have a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}^{10}$ then $a_n:=1$ if $p(f(n)_1,\ldots,f(n)_9)=0$ and $a_n:=0$ otherwise works by the same idea. This sequence is very concrete (or can be made concrete with a concrete bijection $f$) and can easily be calculated by a computer, it does not depend on any model of ZFC whatsoever. However $a_n$ converges if, and only if, $p$ has no zero in $\mathbb{Z}^9$, because such a zero would appear infinitely often due to $f$ having range $\mathbb{Z}^{10}$.

Comment: @JianingSong I slightly changed the answer, but the moral of the story is: once you have $p$, you can play around with it and define a sequence $(a_n)_n$ using it. Similar ideas have been mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Manlio Yes I see, thanks! It is just that "dependence of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" that appears to be not well-defined. After all, when the Wikipedia page says "one can write down a concrete polynomial", I don't know whether this sentence is well-defined (what are exactly the "concrete" things?) ...